# Editing Exim's Banner

Tags: linux, email, smtp, exim

Is there a way to place EXIM smtp banner on 1 line instead of 3 lines? The banner starts with 220. I've been searching but can not find a way.

under /etc/exim.conf I have

```
#todd host's
smtp_banner = "${primary_hostname} ESMTP Exim ${version_number} \
\#${compile_number} ${tod_full} \n\
  We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, \n\
  and/or bulk e-mail."
```

do i make that one line?

Comment: May I ask why?  Have you tried removing the `\n`?  That may be a newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commenter above is correct, it is the "\n" which is putting newlines in your banner.  Quoting the [exim_docs](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch14.html) definition of smtp_banner:

```
This string, which is expanded every time it is used, is output as the
initial positive response to an SMTP connection. The default setting is:

smtp_banner = $smtp_active_hostname ESMTP Exim \
  $version_number $tod_full

Failure to expand the string causes a panic error. If you want to create
a multiline response to the initial SMTP connection, use “\n” in the
string at appropriate points, but not at the end.
```